# Knowing if a link under a form is allowed

Tags: html

Below is the code i want to show you. Is the line of code with the a and href tag allowed?

```
<form class="box" action="index.html" method="post">
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Password">
    <a href="index.html"><input type="submit" name="" value="Sign Up"></a>
 </form>
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1):

No. An input element may not be a descendant of an anchor element.

See the [specification for `a`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element):

> Content model:
>
> Transparent, but there must be no interactive content or a element descendants.

(`input` elements are interactive content).

---

It doesn't make sense to construct that HTML anyway. Clicking on a link navigates to a new page with a GET request. Clicking on a submit button navigates to a new page with a form submission.

Comment: so what code can i use in order to send me to, for example, "index.html" once i click the submit button?

Comment: @SKYPAMPOSAANGELES — You either set the action of the form to `index.html` … which you've done already … or have whatever server-side code you submit the form to redirect to `index.html` with a `Location` response header once it has processed the submitted data.